# .htaccess detect numbers separated by '-'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I couldn't find any helpful resource on the web, so I'm just asking it here
I have my .htaccess file with the following lines of code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^KOP/shop/(\d+)*$ KOP/shop/details.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^KOP/order/(\d+)*$ KOP/order.php?id=$1 [L]
```

When I enter
localhost/KOP/order/1612-8077-68
[I get a page not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOAum.png)

But when I enter
localhost/KOP/order/1612807768
[The rewrite works, and writes out the number from $_GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHHMI.png)

I would like to know what should I change in my code to let it rewrite with the dashes between the numbers.   Is there a line in my .htaccess file telling apache to redirect only numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^KOP/shop/(\d{4})-(\d{4})-(\d{2})$ KOP/shop/details.php?id=$1$2$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^KOP/order/(\d{4})-(\d{4})-(\d{2})$ KOP/order.php?id=$1-$2-$3 [L]  
// Remove the dashes to get only the numbers ↑

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^KOP/shop/(\d+)*$ KOP/shop/details.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^KOP/order/(\d+)*$ KOP/order.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the number without the dashes, but I can format that. Thanks once again.

Comment: I just added dashes between the $1$2$3 on the 5th line, now it works perfectly.

Comment: @kpty, your welcome, you can edit my answer and I will approve it :) cheers and happy learning.